# Compare selected date with current date and cannot more than 1 day

Tags: java, date, diff, difference

Can I have the solution?
I want to get the time that user key in and compare with current time and if the different more than 1 day, it will pop out an error message. What can i do?

```
Iterator i= rows.iterator(); // Iterating grid rows
while (i.hasNext()) {
    FormRow row = (FormRow) i.next();
    String menudt = row.get("menudate");
}


String CurrentDate;
Date date1 = new Date();
Date date2;
SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
//Setting dates
date1.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
CurrentDate = dates.format(date1);
date2 = dates.parse(menudt + " " + "18:00:00"); //There are an error here it cannot change the string to date
date1 = dates.parse(CurrentDate);

long diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

long day = 86400000;


if (diff > day){
       System.out.println("HAHAHAH")
}
```

Comment: Now the problem have been solved but there are another problem at the current date and time, Is there any way to retrieve current date and time to do comparison?

Comment: There is... the method is called `now()` and suitable classes have that method (e.g. `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`...)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the date with this method:

```java
static boolean isValid(String dateString) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"));
    
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
    LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);
    if (date.isBefore(yesterday) || date.isAfter(tomorrow))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Which can be abbreviated to:

```java
static boolean isValid(String dateString) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"));
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    return (! date.isBefore(today.minusDays(1)) && ! date.isAfter(today.plusDays(1)));
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this, which is closer to what you were trying:

```java
static boolean isValid(String dateString) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"));
    return (Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), date)) <= 1);
}
```